# What is the time complexity of the following python code using dictionary?

Tags: python, performance, dictionary, time-complexity

```
def twoSum(self, nums, target):

    compliments = {}
    length = len(nums)

    for i, num in enumerate(nums):
        compliment_of_num = target-num
        if compliment_of_num in compliments:
            return [nums.index(compliment_of_num),i]
        compliments.update({num:compliment_of_num})
```

I think its O(n) but I think the line " if compliment_of_num in compliments" is O(n) instead of O(1) which makes the complexity of the whole program to be O(N^2)

Comment: `O(n)` - the `in` for `dict` (like `set`) is `O(1)`

Comment: So it means that it doesn't matter whether am looking in the set of keys or in the set of values. It's always O(1). Is it correct?

Comment: dictionary is implemented as a  hashtable and its search time is constant O(1)

Comment: No, the keys are O(1), not the values

Comment: https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity This is a good reference it says that sets are O(1) lookup time . I suppose that answers your question

Comment: @ReblochonMasque why do you say it is not `O(1)` for values - do you happen to know the time complexity for `dict.values()` in Py3?

Comment: OP's code should be O(n) + O(1) = O(n) as others have said. One way to convince yourself is to run a test on a million items iteratively and with a dict and compare the results. As for `dict.values()`, I'm pretty sure that's O(n)--how could it be any different? Every entry is iterated over and its value appended to a list.

Comment: I think you are correct @AChampion regarding d.values() returning a view object; however, my understanding is that if you have a dictionary that is like this: `{(1, 2, 3): [random.randrange(0, 10_000_000) for _ in range(100_000_000)]}`, searching if a value is in `dictionary[(1, 2, 3)]`, is not `O(1)`

Comment: That is correct because you are now checking contains of a `list`, but the OP just has simple values in the dict `{num: compliment_of_num}`. So I think providing `dict.values()` is an `O(1)` operation (which I haven't been able to confirm) - the `x in dict.values()` would be an `O(1)` operation.

Comment: @AChampion no it wouldn't, even if `dict.values()` is O(1), and O(1) space, since it is a view, that doesn't mean membership testing is O(1). I'm pretty sure it's O(N), dicts are just fancy hash-maps after all. And I doubt that `dict.values()` creates an underlying hash-set of the values, or even more absurdly, an inverse-mapping, in any event, the `dict_values` view object doesn't support set operations for a reason...

Comment: Sorry I misread the pep, `sets` for `dict.keys` and `dict.items`, multiset (bag) for `dict.values` - and it does say `__contains__()` for `dict.values()` is slow (didn't read far enough).

Comment: @AChampion well, [here's something for the empirically inclined](https://gist.github.com/juanarrivillaga/fb9e54d58a7998f83797f2e71bb259a9)

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga very conclusive.

Comment: Thanks, everyone for the informed discussion. I got my answer.